# Should I learn a new programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

I have dealt and used JavaScript and am quite comfortable with it. However I was wondering if I should learn another one. Is there another language out there that used more widely or has more use in the business industry? And could you also recommend a good book for it?

Comment: it depends upon what do you feel interseted in?

Comment: You should be comfortable with Java and/or C#.

Comment: You should be comfortable with PHP and/or Ruby. NO! There is no one answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Should you learn a new programming language?**

Yes, you surely should.

> **Which one then?**

I don't know. Why don't you pick one related to your expertise? Or something wildly different from what you know.

> **Which book is the best one?**

Go to the library or a book shop. Flip some books through. Most likely, one of those books is good enough. But nothing beats learning to look up API reference on the net.

---

**EDIT:** Question from the comments:

> **What's the most popular and widely used?**

You can use the [TIOBE Community Index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) to look up popular programming languages. However, you shouldn't use that as a deciding factor as things may differ locally to you. I've never done C professionally (which is apparently the most "popular" language according to TIOBE), so it all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Whats the most popular and widely used i guess is the better questions?